# Cannot add color to plotly parcoords graph?

Tags: r, graph, colors, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to create a parallel coordinates graph, but cannot seem to add colour to the lines. Any help appreciated.

I have tries various layers but have had no success. I just get back a chart with black lines.

```
a=c(min(customers[,1+1])-100,max(customers[,1+1])+100)

b=c(min(customers[,1+2])-100,max(customers[,1+2])+100)

c=c(min(customers[,1+3])-100,max(customers[,1+3])+100)

d=c(min(customers[,1+4])-100,max(customers[,1+4])+100)



p <- plot_ly(type = 'parcoords', line = list(color = c('red','blue','green','orange')),
                                             dimensions = list(
                                               list(range = a,

                                                    label = 'A', values = customers[,2]),
                                               list(range = b,
                                                    label = 'B', values = customers[,3]),
                                               list(range = c,
                                                    label = 'C', values = customers[,4]),
                                               list(range = d,
                                                    label = 'D', values = customers[,5])
                                             ),colors=c('red','blue','green','orange')
)

p
```

Data is as follows:

```
Cust_Group Median_V10 Median_V5 Median_V1 Median_v0 Median_NetRev
1  Ctrl_Prem    163.370   357.420   3172.34   9769.17      131.2588
2 Treat_Prem    163.115   505.415   4013.02  10306.07      144.8187
3   Ctrl_Rec    169.880   366.770   3172.14   9769.17      134.7507
4  Treat_Rec    163.115   505.415   4013.02  10306.07      144.8187
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, parallel coordinates plots in Plotly do not currently support categorical colors. As a (somewhat-painful) workaround, you can encode your colors as numbers and then craft a colorscale that ensures that each number renders as the desired color. This example from our docs https://plot.ly/r/parallel-coordinates-plot/#basic-parallel-cordinates-plot shows how to do this. In this case `species_id` is 1, 2 or 3 and the colorscale specifies 3 color values (mapped to 0, 0.5 and 1) which causes each species to render as the matching color.